# How do I show the total marks scored by the user in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I trying to get the total marks from GridView1 and GridView2 but getting syntax error at `total = totalgrid1 + totalgrid2;`

ERROR :- use of unassigned local variables totalgrid1 and totalgrid2.

Marks of GridView1 is stored in totalgrid1 and marks of GridView2 is stored in totalgrid2

I have calculated the value of totalgrid1 and totalgrid2 using `for` loop so its scope is under that `for` loop only , I cannot use the calculated value of totalgrid1 and totalgrid2 outside of that `for` loop then how can I add the calculated marks of totalgrid1 and totalgrid2 ?
Have a look at my code and Please explain me how can I do it ?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;


public partial class Student_Examdemo : System.Web.UI.Page
{



protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack || Session["end_t"] == null)
    {
        DateTime start_time = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime end_time = start_time.AddMinutes(3);
        Session["end_t"] = end_time;
    }

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        GridView1.DataSource = GetData("SELECT top 2 Question, Option1, Option2, Option3, Option4, CorrectAns, Explanation FROM Questions");
        GridView1.DataBind();
        GridView2.DataSource = GetData("SELECT top 2 Question, Option1, Option2, Option3, Option4, CorrectAns, Explanation FROM Questions WHERE SectionId=2");
        GridView2.DataBind();
    }
}

private DataSet GetData(string query)
{
    string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
    {
        using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
        {
            cmd.Connection = con;
            sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
            using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
            {
                sda.Fill(ds);
                return ds;
            }
        }
    }
}

protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RadioButton r1, r2, r3, r4;
    HiddenField hdn;
    int count = 0;
    int neg = 0;
    int total;
    int totalgrid1;
    int totalgrid2;
    string selans = "-1";
    for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        r1 = (RadioButton)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("rad1");
        r2 = (RadioButton)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("rad2");
        r3 = (RadioButton)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("rad3");
        r4 = (RadioButton)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("rad4");
        hdn = (HiddenField)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("hf");
        if (r1.Checked)
        {
            selans = r1.Text;
        }
        else if (r2.Checked)
        {
            selans = r2.Text;
        }
        else if (r3.Checked)
        {
            selans = r3.Text;
        }
        else if (r4.Checked)
        {
            selans = r4.Text;
        }

        if (hdn.Value == selans)
        {
            count++;
        }
        else
        {
           neg--;
        }
        Totalgrid1 = count + neg;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < GridView2.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        r1 = (RadioButton)GridView2.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("rad1");
        r2 = (RadioButton)GridView2.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("rad2");
        r3 = (RadioButton)GridView2.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("rad3");
        r4 = (RadioButton)GridView2.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("rad4");
        hdn = (HiddenField)GridView2.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("hf");
        if (r1.Checked)
        {
            selans = r1.Text;
        }
        else if (r2.Checked)
        {
            selans = r2.Text;
        }
        else if (r3.Checked)
        {
            selans = r3.Text;
        }
        else if (r4.Checked)
        {
            selans = r4.Text;
        }

        if (hdn.Value == selans)
        {
            count++;
        }
        else
        {
            neg--;
        }
        totalgrid2 = count + neg;
    }
    total = totalgrid1 + totalgrid2;
}
protected void timer1_tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime dt = (DateTime)Session["end_t"];
    DateTime dt_curr = DateTime.Now;
    TimeSpan ts = dt - dt_curr;
    lblTimer.Text = ts.Hours.ToString() + ":" + ts.Minutes.ToString() + ":" + ts.Seconds.ToString();
    if (ts.Minutes == 0)
    {
        timer1.Enabled = false;
        Response.Redirect("/Student/Result.aspx");
    }
}

}


<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Examdemo.aspx.cs" Inherits="Student_Examdemo" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form2" runat="server">
        <div>

        <div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Tab 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-4">Tab 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-5">Tab 5</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" >
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Question") %>'></asp:Label>
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
           <asp:RadioButton ID="rad1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Option1") %>' GroupName="A" />
            <asp:RadioButton ID="rad2" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Option2") %>' GroupName="A" />
            <asp:RadioButton ID="rad3" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Option3") %>' GroupName="A" />
            <asp:RadioButton ID="rad4" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Option4") %>' GroupName="A" />
            <asp:HiddenField ID="hf" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("CorrectAns") %>' />

        <br />
        <br />

                 </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">


        <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" >
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Question") %>'></asp:Label>
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
           <asp:RadioButton ID="rad1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Option1") %>' GroupName="A" />
            <asp:RadioButton ID="rad2" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Option2") %>' GroupName="A" />
            <asp:RadioButton ID="rad3" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Option3") %>' GroupName="A" />
            <asp:RadioButton ID="rad4" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Optiont4") %>' GroupName="A" />
            <asp:HiddenField ID="hf" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("CorrectAns") %>' />

        <br />
        <br />

                 </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
        Tab 3 Content
    </div>
     <div id="tabs-4">
        Tab 4 Content
    </div>
     <div id="tabs-5">
        Tab 5 Content
    </div>
</div>
<input type="button" id="btnPrevious" value="Previous" style = "display:none"/>
<input type="button" id="btnNext" value="Next" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

            <asp:Button class="panelButton" runat="server" Text="Finish the exam" ClientIDMode="Static" OnClick="btn_Click" />
            <br />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Initialize `totalgrid1` and `totalgrid2` to zero at the declaration.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with the scope of your variables as they're both defined in the button click event.  You have 2 problems here:

1) In the first for-loop you set Totalgrid1 instead of totalgrid1

2) your variables are un-initialized.  At the top of the button click event where you define the variables, set them to 0

```
int totalgrid1 = 0;
int totalgrid2 = 0;
```